# How to make an inline-block container's left and right margins always equal?

Tags: html, css

I have a grouping of containers within another container. For clarification, here's the HTML:

```
<div class = "box-grouping">
    <div class = "box-section grey">
        <h2>What We Do</h2>
    </div>
    <div class = "box-section grey">
        <h2>Where We Are</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

At the preferred resolution, the two boxes would be side by side, with the first box's left margin being equal to the second box's right margin, plus some space in between each. When I design in half my resolution, it looks like [this](http://prntscr.com/n62sn6). That's fine, except when I raise the resolution to full size, it looks like [this](http://prntscr.com/n62w8i). As you can see, the left and right margins are not equal.

I've tried setting the left and right margins to auto, but that didn't work. Here's the CSS I'm using:

```
.box-section {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I'd like the page to look like the half resolution screenshot, in any resolution. Additionally, the containers always appear too big in full resolution, but when I try to scale them down, they get too small for smaller resolutions. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: since they are `inline-block`, maybe you could try setting both box-sections `margin: 0 30px;` and set `text-align: center;` on the parent container box-grouping. Also, you may want to remove the margin from the width calculation... so the width would be `calc(40% - 60px);`

Comment: what is the css for box-grouping? maybe you can go with margin: auto for box-grouping, and give it a width of your choice

Comment: The first suggestions worked great. When I use `calc()`, it raises an error, as if it's not a valid function. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ChrisLallo are you using less or sass? should look like this in normal CSS... `width: calc(40% - 60px);`

Comment: Oh I just removed the width property, whoops. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set `text-align: center` to your `.box-grouping` class to center the boxes. Then, in your `.box-section` class, change your `margin-left: 60px` to `margin: 0 30px` to apply an even margin to both of the `.box-section divs`.

With the way your code is currently, you will need to add a media query to shrink the boxes to prevent wrapping for smaller devices.

```css
.box-grouping {
  text-align: center;
}

.box-section {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 30px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-grouping">
  <div class="box-section grey">
    <h2>What We Do</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="box-section grey">
    <h2>Where We Are</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can change the width to `width: calc(40% - 60px);`, that way it won't wrap on smaller devices. no need for media query

Answer (score 2):

You could make the parent div display flex like such.

```
.box-grouping {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.box-section {
    flex: 0 1 40%; /* this means -> flex:[grow] [shrink] [width]; */
    display: inline-block;
    height: 300px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

HTML

```
<div class = "box-grouping">
    <div class = "box-section grey float-left">
        <h2>What We Do</h2>
    </div>
    <div class = "box-section grey float-right">
        <h2>Where We Are</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box-section {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
    height: 300px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}

.float-left {
  float: left;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}

.box-grouping {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Working [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LvErJP)

Comment: Since this is inline, what happens when a small resolution forces the two elements onto different lines? Wouldn't the float cause an issue?

Comment: i've just tested it in a very small resolution, it doesn't break onto 2 lines, since the width is reduced a bit. can you check the codepen ?

Comment: Yeah that does work. My last issue is that when I add content inside each of the inner divs, it causes them to go up (or make the empty one go down, I'm not sure). You can see that here: http://prntscr.com/n63cpi How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<div class = "box-grouping">
    <div class = "box-section grey">
        <h2>What We Do</h2>
    </div>
    <div class = "box-section grey">
        <h2>Where We Are</h2>
    </div>
</div>
</html>


<style>
.box-section {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    height: 300px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}

.box-grouping {
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

Comment: `align-content: center;` is used for elements with `display: flex;`. Nothing here is flex

Answer (score -1):

*Change the second box class name to a different  name

*And float the first box to the left. And float the second box to the right.

- I usually give my container a width off 100%.

Now for the first box give it the margin you want like margin-left 10px.

Now for the second box give it the same margin. Margin-right 10px.

Now for the spacing in between the two boxes.  if you want it to be 6px. Give each box 3px margin.